# Could I limit upload bandwidth for outgoing messages from exim4?

Tags: exim, bandwidth-control

Hello serverfault community,

Does anybody used an iptables rule or know an exim4 configuration setting to limit upload bandwidth??

All the ways I've found through google was with proxies which I don't prefer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options for traffic shaping

- Use [tc](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) directly.
- Use some tool more convenient like [shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/simple_traffic_shaping.html).